# Верстка меню с линией внизу

Tags: html, css

Застопорился с линией внизу, нужен ваш совет реализации[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.banner__list {
 list-style: none;
}

.banner__item {
 padding-bottom: 3px;
 margin-right: 68px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
.banner__item:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #050;
}

.banner__item:after {
  position:absolute;
}

.banner__menu {
 margin: auto;
 max-width: 573px;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #444;
}

.banner__item {
 display: inline-block
}
.banner__link {
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
 <div class="banner__menu">
  <ul class="banner__list">
   <li class="banner__item">
    <a href="" class="banner__link">
     
    
     Антивирус
    </a>
   </li>
   <li class="banner__item">
    <a href="" class="banner__link">
     
     
     Wifire
    </a>
   </li>
   <li class="banner__item">
    
    <a href="" class="banner__link">
     
     
     Интернет
    </a>
   </li>
   <li class="banner__item">
    
    <a href="" class="banner__link">
     
     
     Life
    </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Какие проблемы? border-bottom серого цвета, а у того пункта меню, что выделен, должен быть свой короткий border-bottom поверх. А чтобы поверх - position: absolute в :after

Comment: когда задаю border-bottom серого цвета, линия получается на всю ширину контейнера 1400px

Comment: ну так оберните меню в промежуточный div нужной ширины

Comment: position: absolute в :after не помогает, цветная линия не накладывается поверх

Comment: Приведите ваш код, вам помогут

Comment: Привел пример кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо использовать :hover :after, см. код.

```css
.banner__list {
  list-style: none;
}

.banner__item {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  margin-right: 68px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.banner__item:hover {}

.banner__item:hover :after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 21px;
}

.banner__menu {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 573px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #444;
}

.banner__item {
  display: inline-block
}

.banner__link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner__menu">
  <ul class="banner__list">
    <li class="banner__item">
      <a href="" class="banner__link">
     
    
     Антивирус
    </a>
    </li>
    <li class="banner__item">
      <a href="" class="banner__link">
     
     
     Wifire
    </a>
    </li>
    <li class="banner__item">

      <a href="" class="banner__link">
     
     
     Интернет
    </a>
    </li>
    <li class="banner__item">

      <a href="" class="banner__link">
     
     
     Life
    </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```